# jQuery click vs. drag drop

Tags: jquery, events, click

I use clippy.JS (https://www.smore.com/clippy-js) a JS-version of the much hated agents from older office versions (as a joke)

I want to add an event handler that fires when the user clicks onto the image. But when moving the image with the mouse with the build in drag/drop possibilities the jQuery.click - event is also thrown.

How can I find out if the user clicked or moved the image?